# The Theory of Probabilistic Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, mathematical-physics

${P}_m := \{ \Phi_{1m}, \Phi_{2m}, \ldots , \Phi_{nm} \}$  where $$|\Phi_{im} \rangle = \wp_{1m}  | \phi_1 \rangle + \wp_{2m} | \phi_{2m} \rangle + \cdots + \wp_{km} | \phi_{km} \rangle$$ such that $\wp_{im}$ is a probability amplitude for $\Phi_{im} \in \mathbb{P}_m$ being in it's $i^{th}$ state, $\phi_{im} $ Probability amplitudes are defined in such  a way that $|\wp_{1m}|^2 + |\wp_{2m}|^2 + \cdots + |\wp_{km}|^2 = 1$
 and let $\mathbb{P}_m | i \rangle$ be the set $\mathbb{P}_m$ with each of its elements in the $i^{th}$ state. We define the sets to not be pairwise disjoint in the following way:

Let $N$ be an index set such that $\forall m \in N$ let   $\mathbb{P}_m$ be a set. Therefore we have $$ \mathbb{P}_m \mid  \bigcap_{m \in N} \mathbb{P}_m | i \rangle\neq O$$ in other words  $\exists \phi_{i1} , \phi_{i2} , \ldots , \phi_{in} \in \mathbb{P}_1, \mathbb{P}_2, \ldots, \mathbb{P}_n  \mid \phi_{i1} \equiv \phi_{i2}  \equiv \cdots \equiv \phi_{in} $

**The Mathematics of Probabilistic Sets**

A Probabilistic Set can be thought of as a set of normalised wave functions $\Phi_{im}$  that have at least one state in common and therefore have a finite probability of intersection.

*Union of Probabilistic Sets*

The union of probabilistic sets can be defined quite trivially as $$\bigcup_{m \in N} \mathbb{P}_m : = \{ \Phi_{11}, \Phi_{12}, \ldots, \Phi_{1N}, \Phi_{21}, \Phi_{22}, \ldots,  \Phi_{2N}, \ldots ,\Phi_{1n}, \Phi_{2n}, \ldots, \Phi_{nN} \}$$
 *Intersection of Probabilistic Sets*
 It should be fairly clear that two probabilistic sets $\mathbb{P}_m$ and $\mathbb{P}_K$ do not have a well defined intersection. Instead we may discuss the \textit{probability} of two such sets intersecting. \
 The probability of intersection of the probabilistic sets shall be denoted $$\mathcal{P} \Big( \bigcap_{m \in N} \mathbb{P}_m | i \rangle \Big)$$ 
We can define $\Phi_{im} (\phi_{im})$ to be the wave function for $\Phi_{im}$ where $\phi_{im}  \equiv  [\alpha_i, \beta_i]$. So we define a state $\phi_{im}$ to be the corresponding interval $[\alpha_i,\beta_i]$ on the wave function $\Phi_{im} (\phi_{im})$. It now follows that the probability of finding the element $\Phi_{im}$ in the state $\phi_{im}$ is given by 
$$ P_{\phi_{im} \in \Phi_{im}} = \int_{\alpha_i}^{\beta_i} d \phi_{im} \Big| \Phi_{im} (\phi_{im}) \Big|^2$$
If only one such $\phi_{im}$ per set exists satisfying $\phi_{i1} , \phi_{i2} , \ldots , \phi_{in} \in \mathbb{P}_1, \mathbb{P}_2, \ldots, \mathbb{P}_n  \mid \phi_{i1} \equiv \phi_{i2}  \equiv \cdots \equiv \phi_{in} $, then the probability of the intersection of sets is given by 
$$ \mathcal{P} \Big( \bigcap_{m \in N} \mathbb{P}_m | i \rangle \Big) = \prod_{m \in N} \Big( \int_{\alpha_i}^{\beta_i} d \phi_{im} \Big| \Phi_{im} (\phi_{im}) \Big|^2 \Big)_m$$ 
However if two such states are equivalent per set, call this second equivalent state $\phi_{jm}$ the probability becomes 
$$  \mathcal{P} \Big( \bigcap_{m \in N} \mathbb{P}_m | i \rangle \Big) = \prod_{m \in N} \Big( \int_{\alpha_i}^{\beta_i} d \phi_{im} \Big| \Phi_{im} (\phi_{im}) \Big|^2  + \int_{\alpha_j}^{\beta_j} d \phi_{jm} \Big| \Phi_{jm} (\phi_{jm}) \Big|^2 \Big)_m$$
Now we extend this to the obvious case of: what if such elements share $\mathfrak{R}$ equivalent states? Well intuitively the probability of such an intersection occurring  approaches $1$ as $\mathfrak{R} \to n$.
Trivially following from the previous two equations, the probability of intersection is given by  $$  \mathcal{P} \Big( \bigcap_{m \in N} \mathbb{P}_m | i \rangle \Big) = \prod_{m \in N} \Big(  \sum_{\mathfrak{r} \leq \mathfrak{R}} \Big( \int_{\alpha_i}^{\beta_i} d \phi_{im} \Big| \Phi_{im} (\phi_{im}) \Big|^2 \Big)_\mathfrak{r}  \Big)_m$$

*Is everything I'm doing thus far correct? Is anything I'm doing thus far correct? I was just brainstorming ideas and this is what I came up with so I'd like to know if I'm right. Thanks*
Any input is appreciated

Comment: I wasn't sure on the tags. If anyone feels they have more appropriate tags, please, feel free to change them

Comment: I would avoid the use of $\wp$ for anything except the Weierstrass elliptic function.

Comment: @deoxygerbe Noted. I'll fix that

Comment: It seems like you're trying to state your entire theory in its full generality right away. That way lies madness! Can you start with $n=N=2$ and replace the integrals with sums, so that you can build intuition while keeping the notation simple? By the way, in the context of quantum mechanics, $[a,b]$ looks more like a commutator than an interval.

Comment: @ChrisCutler What sums do you mean to replace the integrals with? & how should I denote an interval then?

Comment: @AnthonyPeter That's not my name. :) I'm not entirely sure what the integrals mean... It seems like you have a variable $\phi_{im}$ which takes values in an interval of real numbers. Is that necessary? Can you start by letting $\phi_{im}$ take values in the set $\{0,1\}$ instead?

Comment: @ChrisCulter My apologies. I'm directly applying the formula for the probability of finding a particle in a given interval. I couldn't think of a better way to find the probability. Also if I let it take binary values, wouldn't it be remarkably similar to a fuzzy set? Just a mild extension using probability?

Comment: @AnthonyPeter Okay, if intervals are what you're interested in, then you'll want to keep them around. But what are $n$, $N$, $m$, and $i$? Are you representing multiple particles in multiple dimensions? Can any of these be set to $1$ or $2$?

Comment: @ChrisCulter $i, m $ are just arbitrary.  $N$ is just the set of all probabilistic sets, $n$ is the length of each set. Not sure how that relates to a particle system.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter If a simplification of your theory reduces to a known theory, that's fantastic! It means that you've invented a generalization! If you could say something like "$n=1$ reduces to set theory, $n=2$ reduces to fuzzy set theory, and $n=3$ is a totally new theory with interesting properties", how awesome would that be? Instead of shying away from such comparisons, you can use them to help explain what you're doing and how it relates to the mathematics that people already know.

Comment: @ChrisCulter I understand what you're saying, and that seems rather interesting. Do you mean $k=1,2,3$ instead of $n=1,2,3$? Because if only one state exists, then it should reduce to set theory, and if two states exist, then it should reduce to fuzzy set theory.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter Oh, I don't know about $k$ and $n$; I was just spitballing. The letter $k$ wasn't defined anywhere... You'll probably want to lay out what all of your notation means. For example, if $k$ is the number of states, don't leave it to the reader to figure that out; just say "$k$ is the number of states". If you could write up an explanation of these connections, I'd be very interested in reading it!

Comment: @ChrisCulter Well it seems to me without too much rigor, that if $k=1$, the set would simply be a normal set as it can only take on one possible value. While if $k=2$, the set has a probability of being in one of two states. Now since it's only a probability that the element will take on one of two states, each element can have a degree of membership to the set according to its probability amplitude. aka a sort of definition of a fuzzy set. Is my intuition right?

Comment: @AnthonyPeter It seems as though that is intuitively correct to me

Comment: @AnthonyPeter I don't know, because it's all too complex for me to tell what's going on. :) There are more symbols than explanations, and there's no learning curve; it's just *bam* everything all at once. You've got to scaffold these things. Choose the smallest possible atom of an idea, define it, explain it, give it intuition, work out 1-3 examples. Then you can give it subscripts and make it part of a larger structure. Define, explain, work out examples. I think you're probably doing something interesting but I have no idea what it is...

Comment: @ChrisCulter I apologize :) I was in class only a day ago when this idea came to me. So this theory is ridiculously new. That's why I posted it here to see if I was doing anything right whatsoever. Granted I've taken college math courses, but from a physics perspective, this is out of the league of a high school student. This is all I've been able to figure out in the course of two nights

Comment: @AnthonyPeter That's impressive! Well, if you make any more progress on explanations and/or examples, please update the question; I'd like to take a look!